# Spark Working with custom UADF in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write a UADF which collects all values to a list but only keeps the X top/bottom values.

I have started with doing the collect to list part (ignoring the limit to values) and even though it appears to work, I am getting weird exceptions.

This is what I got so far:

I have created a custom UADF as follows:

```
/*
 * An aggregate function to collect time series information
*/
package com.test.test1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.MutableAggregationBuffer;
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

/**
 * A class to perform aggregate function for time series.
 * 
 * This class generates aggregate function (e.g. in groupBy) on a dataframe.
 * It collects the values into a list but limits it to the top (bottom) X values.
 * @note While we added the maximum number of values to keep to the constructor, this is not yet 
 *       integrated in the code
 */
public class TimeSeriesAggregateFunction extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
    /** 
     * Defines the input schema (initialized in the constructor to be a Long (for timestamps). 
     * 
     * @note If other types are required then another implementation is needed. The best way to work
     *       with this in pyspark is to cast to long
     */
    private final StructType _inputDataType;
    /**
     * Internal buffer schema (initialized in constructor). It is assumed to be a simple ArrayList
     */
    private final StructType _bufferSchema;
    /**
     * output schema (initialized in constructor). It is assumed to be a simple ArrayList of Long.
     */
    private final DataType _returnDataType;
    /**
     * The maximum allowed number of elements. 
     * Positive value 'x' means the largest X values would be saved (newest timestamps)
     * Zero value means no limit.
     * Negative value 'x' means the smallest X values would be saved (oldest timestamps)
     */
    private final int maxLen;

    public TimeSeriesAggregateFunction(int _maxLen) {
        // init input to be Long
        List<StructField> inputFields = new ArrayList<StructField>();
        inputFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("inputDouble", DataTypes.LongType, true));
        _inputDataType = DataTypes.createStructType(inputFields);

        // init buffer to be an array of long. NOTE: No nulls allowed
        List<StructField> bufferFields = new ArrayList<StructField>();
        bufferFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("bufferDoubleArray", DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.LongType, false) , false));
        _bufferSchema = DataTypes.createStructType(bufferFields);

        // init buffer to be an array of long. NOTE: No nulls allowed (empty array is provided if needed)
        _returnDataType = DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.LongType, false);

        maxLen = _maxLen;
    }

    /**
     * this tells the inherited class of our input schema (we only HAVE to have this, not the 
     * internal type)
     * @return input schema
     */
    @Override public StructType inputSchema() {
        return _inputDataType;
    }

    /**
     * this tells the inherited class of our buffer schema (we only HAVE to have this, not the 
     * internal type)
     * @return Buffer schema
     */
    @Override public StructType bufferSchema() {
        return _bufferSchema;
    }

    /**
     * this tells the inherited class of our output schema (we only HAVE to have this, not the 
     * internal type)
     * @return output schema
     */
    @Override public DataType dataType() {
        return _returnDataType;
    }

    /**
     * Tells the inherited class that we will always give the same result to the same input
     * @return True
     */
    @Override public boolean deterministic() {        
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Used to initialize the buffer
     * @param buffer to initialize
     */
    @Override public void initialize(MutableAggregationBuffer buffer) {
        // We initialize to an empty array as we would ALWAYS have a result.
        buffer.update(0, new ArrayList());
    }

    /**
     * Used to update the buffer with the value from a single row
     * @param buffer The buffer to update
     * @param input The data from the row (can be one or more columns, depending on the input schema
     *              definition. In our case it is the column we want to turn to an array).
     */
    @Override public void update(MutableAggregationBuffer buffer, Row input) {
        // we only update when we have a valid input (null can occur in certain cases).
        if (!input.isNullAt(0)) {
            // NOTE: We keep creating a new object each time. Need to figure out if we can avoid 
            //       this to avoid garbage collection
            ArrayList newList = new ArrayList(buffer.getList(0));
            newList.add(input.getLong(0));
            buffer.update(0,newList);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Used to merge two buffers (usually when merging the results of two different partitions).
     * @param buffer1 The buffer to update
     * @param buffer2 The data from the row (can be one or more columns, depending on the input schema
     *              definition. In our case it is the column we want to turn to an array).
     */
    @Override public void merge(MutableAggregationBuffer buffer1, Row buffer2) {
        // buffer1 and buffer2 have the same structure.
        // We only update the buffer1 when the input buffer2's value is not empty (it should never
        // be null even though we check but it could be empty).
        if(buffer2.isNullAt(0) || buffer2.getList(0).isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        if (buffer1.isNullAt(0) || buffer1.getList(0).isEmpty()) {
            buffer1.update(0, new ArrayList(buffer2.getList(0)));
            return;
        }
        ArrayList newList = new ArrayList(buffer1.getList(0));
        newList.addAll(buffer2.getList(0));
        buffer1.update(0, newList);
    }

    /**
     * When we finish collecting the buffer this turns it into the output.
     * @param buffer The buffer we collected
     * @return The output value.
     */
    @Override public Object evaluate(Row buffer) {
        return buffer.getList(0);
    }
}
```

In pyspark notebook I define a wrapper as follows:

```
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import
from pyspark.sql.column import Column, _to_java_column, _to_seq
from pyspark.sql import Row
jvm = sc._gateway.jvm
java_import(jvm, "com.test.test1.TimeSeriesAggregateFunction")
seriesAggregation = jvm.com.test.test1.TimeSeriesAggregateFunction(10)
def myCol2(col):
    castcol = col.cast(pyspark.sql.types.LongType())
    return Column(seriesAggregation.apply(_to_seq(sc,[castcol], _to_java_column)))
```

I then run it as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
newdf = df.groupBy(["myKey"]).agg(myCol2(df.time).alias("timeSeries"),F.count(df.time).alias("CountTime"))
```

Everything seems fine both when I use a dummy dataframe and real data, however, when I use real data I get the following exception several times:

```
16/03/13 10:25:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 944.0 in stage 18.0 (TID 11845, ds-hdfs-05.nwlabs.local): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.GenericArrayData cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
        at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow$class.getLong(rows.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericMutableRow.getLong(rows.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.JoinedRow.getLong(JoinedRow.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificMutableProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$11.apply(AggregationIterator.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$11.apply(AggregationIterator.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.SortBasedAggregationIterator.processCurrentSortedGroup(SortBasedAggregationIterator.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.SortBasedAggregationIterator.next(SortBasedAggregationIterator.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.SortBasedAggregationIterator.next(SortBasedAggregationIterator.scala:30)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.insertAll(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:119)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I get this around 3-8 times (it differs with multiple runs). I run with 25 executors (so this doesn't happen on every merge). The result seems fine even thought the exception exists (and as I said it returns several times but continues successfully).

So my main question is, what does this exception mean (and how to fix it).

As a side question, I was wondering if there is a better way to implement such a function (specifically, it seems to me that all the "new" in the update and merge would cost a lot of performance (both in the object generation and on garbage collection) when I move to bigger data.

**UPDATE**
I have tried to call this directly from scala by saving the dataframe to file and in scala shell (with the same switches as I used in pyspark) I did the following:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("/mapr/DScluster/assaf_temp/scala_df_test/*")
import com.test.test1._
val a = new TimeSeriesAggregateFunction(10)
val b = df.groupBy("root","ip_src").agg(max(df.col("refererNull")).as("refererNull"),max(df.col("clientNull")).as("clientNull"), a(df.col("time2")).as("timeSeries"), count(df.col("time2")).as("CountTime"))
b.show()
```

This time I got multiple exceptions. Some of them look the same as before and in addition a different exception:

```
Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1496)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1447)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1824)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1837)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1850)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1385)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1385)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:1903)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collect(DataFrame.scala:1384)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1314)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:178)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:401)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:370)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:29)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:34)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:44)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:46)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:48)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:50)
        at <init>(<console>:52)
        at .<init>(<console>:56)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:674)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayData
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow$class.getArray(rows.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericMutableRow.getArray(rows.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.JoinedRow.getArray(JoinedRow.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificMutableProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$29.apply(AggregationIterator.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$29.apply(AggregationIterator.scala:339)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.SortBasedAggregationIterator.next(SortBasedAggregationIterator.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.SortBasedAggregationIterator.next(SortBasedAggregationIterator.scala:30)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.insertAll(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:119)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

BTW I am running spark version 1.5.2

Output of printSchema:

```
|-- filename: string (nullable = true)
|-- directory: string (nullable = true)
|-- rpayload: integer (nullable = true)
|-- action: string (nullable = true)
|-- ip_dst: string (nullable = true)
|-- client: string (nullable = true)
|-- service: integer (nullable = true)
|-- payload: integer (nullable = true)
|-- time: long (nullable = true)
|-- sessionid: long (nullable = true)
|-- ip_src: string (nullable = true)
|-- query: string (nullable = true)
|-- unique_id: string (nullable = true)
|-- alias_host: string (nullable = true)
|-- tcp_dstport: integer (nullable = true)
|-- udp_dstport: integer (nullable = true)
|-- alias_ip: string (nullable = true)
|-- referer: string (nullable = true)
|-- content: string (nullable = true)
|-- http_response: string (nullable = true)
|-- root: string (nullable = true)
|-- url: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Do you experience the same problems when you use this function directly (Java / Scala)?

Comment: Are you sure you get this with simplified version? And could you add the output from `df.printSchema`?

Comment: With printSchema I get that time is long (nullable=true)

Comment: I do not get the error when using sample data (df.parallelize(range(1000000))), only on real data.